# Add values to list and change type to int

Tags: python

I'm scraping a page that sometimes gives me a list with 5 values and sometimes less than that. I need to format these lists so all of them have 5 values, all integers. These lists will be added to a JSON later, so they need to follow the same pattern.

But I'm not being able to do this. The values aren't being changed to integers as expected.

**EXAMPLE AND EXPECTED**

```
scraped alement:  
all_lst = [['\n                    35,726\n                ', 
            '\n                    61\n                ', 
            8764, 
            '\n                    11,756\n             ',
            '\n                    3,417\n                '], 
           ['\n                    185,620\n                ',
            '\n                    116\n                ', 
            41823]]

expected result:  
all_lst = [[35726, 61, 8764, 11756, 3417], [185620, 116, 41823, 185620, 116]]
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

```
for lst in all_lst:

    if len(lst) == 5:
        for i in range(5):
            if type(lst[i]) == str:
                lst[i] = int(lst[i].replace(' ','').replace('\n','').replace(',',''))
            else:
                lst[i] = lst[i]
    else:
        lst = list(islice(cycle(lst), 5))
        for i in range(5):
            if type(lst[i]) == str:
                lst[i] = int(lst[i].replace(' ','').replace('\n','').replace(',',''))
            else:
                lst[i] = lst[i]
```

The output now is
[[35726, 61, 8764, 11756, 3417], ['\n                    185,620\n                ', '\n                    116\n                ', 41823]]

Comment: What happens (output, full error messages)? Edit the question to show it.

Comment: Added to the post @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only problem is that you are changing `lst` at the same time as you use it as an iterator. You are cutting the branch you are sitting on. Instead, initialize an empty list and add your items to it.

```
lst_out = list()

for lst in all_lst:
    if len(lst) == 5:
        for i in range(5):
            if type(lst[i]) == str:
                lst[i] = int(lst[i].replace(' ','').replace('\n','').replace(',',''))

    else:
        lst = list(islice(cycle(lst), 5))
        for i in range(5):
            if type(lst[i]) == str:
                lst[i] = int(lst[i].replace(' ','').replace('\n','').replace(',',''))


    lst_out.append(lst)

print(lst_out)
```

Edit: Deleted `list[i] = list[i]` which has no effect.

Comment: Your code gives the correct output but the explanation is quite wrong. The OP's problem is that the code in the `else` block creates a new list with the `list` constructor but then modifies only the new list instead of the original list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension like this instead:

```
[[int(str(i).replace(',', '')) for i in islice(cycle(l), 5)] for l in all_lst]
```

This returns:

```
[[35726, 61, 8764, 11756, 3417], [185620, 116, 41823, 185620, 116]]
```